# Connection To Poco Websocket Server gets Disconnected even when the server side is still listening

Tags: c++, websocket, poco, poco-libraries

**Update**: I can run the server and client perfect locally when they are on the same host. The below scenario is when they are on separate machines(more specifically one is running on ARM64 Petalinux and other on Ubuntu). Perhaps I need to set some options on server side etc

I have a poco websocket server written over the standard sample provided by Poco and a javascript client. While trying to openwebsocket it will get connected in first go sometimes after trying 2-3 times and so on. Now once connected, it might send the message or just gets disconnected on the client side. While on the server side there is no error and I am pretty sure its still open because when i try to open another connection from the client side it will get connected on different client port.

Now the interesting thing is I wrote a Poco websocket client and sending/receiving message continuously without delay in a loop, the client remains active for sometime and then both server and client says Exception connection reset by peer. Next when i put a delay in the loop while sending/receiving messages on client side (say 5s), the client will send/receive for say 3-4 times and then the client encounters Exception connection reset by peer and now this time no such message on server side. Its really boggling me since I couldn't find the solution no matter what i try.
PS: I have timeout of 10 days for websocket server

The server side request handling is as follow:

```
std::cout << "Request Received" << std::endl;
Poco::Util::Application& app = Poco::Util::Application::instance();
try
{
    std::cout << "Trying to connect..." << std::endl;
    Poco::Net::WebSocket ws(request, response);
    ws.setReceiveTimeout(Poco::Timespan(10, 0, 0, 0, 0)); //Timeout of 10 days
    app.logger().information("WebSocket connection established!");

    int flags, n;

    do
    {
        char buffer[1024] = {'\0'};

        std::cout << "Waiting for incoming frame" << std::endl;
        n = ws.receiveFrame(buffer, sizeof(buffer), flags);
        strncpy(buffer, "Hello Client!!", 1024);
        ws.sendFrame(buffer, strlen(buffer), Poco::Net::WebSocket::FRAME_TEXT);
    }
    while (n > 0 && (flags & Poco::Net::WebSocket::FRAME_OP_BITMASK) != Poco::Net::WebSocket::FRAME_OP_CLOSE);
    std::cout << "Websocket Closed" << std::endl;
    app.logger().information("WebSocket connection closed.");
}

catch (std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout << "Exception " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

(As one can see, server will post a message when a websocket is closed but nothing is displayed when the client says connection reset by peer)

The poco websocket client side is:

```
HTTPClientSession cs("IP", port);    
HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, "/?encoding=text",HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
request.set("origin", "http://localhost");
HTTPResponse response;
bool run = true;

try {
    WebSocket* m_psock = new WebSocket(cs, request, response);
    char buffer[1024] = {'\0'};
    std::string str = "Hello Server!!";

    do {
        char receiveBuff[256];
        strncpy(buffer, str.c_str(), 1024);
        int len=m_psock->sendFrame(buffer,strlen(buffer),WebSocket::FRAME_TEXT);
        std::cout << "Sent bytes " << len << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Sent Message:  " << buffer << std::endl;
        int flags=0;

        int rlen=m_psock->receiveFrame(receiveBuff,256,flags);
        std::cout << "Received bytes " << rlen << std::endl;
        std::cout << receiveBuff << std::endl;
        //std::cin >> str;
        sleep(5); 
    } while (1);

    m_psock->close();

} 

catch (std::exception &e) 
{
    std::cout << "Exception " << e.what();
}
```

FYI: I can't process the connection reset by peer, because it directly goes to exception without printing received bytes as 0